Install data.table library in R: zlib.h no such file or directory
I want to install the data.table library in R, but I have problems.
When I type
install.packages("data.table")
it tells me that I have to compile the library from source. If I say yes, my C compiler starts running until the error message comes that <zlib.h> was not found.
So I also tried to install the zlib.h library (using MSYS2, I tried  both pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-zlib and pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib ), but it seems to have been of no use.
Here is my complete output:
imelf@DESKTOP-CFHKUQA MINGW32 /d/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/SteuberHenry/DataAnalysis
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-zlib
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) mingw-w64-i686-zlib-1.3.1-1

Total Download Size:   0.10 MiB
Total Installed Size:  0.40 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
:: Retrieving packages...
 mingw-w64-i686-zlib-1.3.1-...   103.3 KiB   294 KiB/s 00:00 [###############################] 100%
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                               [###############################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                             [###############################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                  [###############################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                            [###############################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                          [###############################] 100% 
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) upgrading mingw-w64-i686-zlib                          [###############################] 100%

imelf@DESKTOP-CFHKUQA MINGW32 /d/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/SteuberHenry/DataAnalysis
$ r

R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> install.packages("data.table");
Installing package into 'C:/Users/imelf/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
           binary source needs_compilation
data.table 1.15.2 1.15.4              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)$           
$$
installing the source package 'data.table'

trying URL 'https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/cran/src/contrib/data.table_1.15.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 5387593 bytes (5.1 MB)
downloaded 5.1 MB

* installing *source* package 'data.table' ...
** package 'data.table' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c assign.c -o assign.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c between.c -o between.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c bmerge.c -o bmerge.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c chmatch.c -o chmatch.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c cj.c -o cj.o      
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c coalesce.c -o coalesce.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c dogroups.c -o dogroups.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c fastmean.c -o fastmean.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c fcast.c -o fcast.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c fifelse.c -o fifelse.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c fmelt.c -o fmelt.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c forder.c -o forder.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c frank.c -o frank.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c fread.c -o fread.o
In file included from fread.c:21:
fread.c: In function ‘freadMain’:
fread.c:1291:21: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
 1291 |       if (isspace(ch[0]) || isspace(ch[nchar-1]))
      |                   ~~^~~
fread.c:1291:39: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
 1291 |       if (isspace(ch[0]) || isspace(ch[nchar-1]))
      |                                     ~~^~~~~~~~~
fread.c:1487:34: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
 1487 |       while (++ch<eof && isspace(*ch)) {};
      |                                  ^~~
fread.c:1570:29: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
 1570 |   while (ch<eof && (isspace(*ch) || *ch=='\0')) {   // isspace matches ' ', \t, \n and \r;  \0 before eof should be skipped too
      |                             ^~~
fread.c:2588:30: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
 2588 |     while (ch<eof && isspace(*ch)) ch++;
      |                              ^~~
fread.c:2595:32: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
 2595 |       while (ch<eof && isspace(*ch)) ch++;
      |                                ^~~
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c freadR.c -o freadR.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c froll.c -o froll.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c frollR.c -o frollR.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c frolladaptive.c -o frolladaptive.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c fsort.c -o fsort.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c fwrite.c -o fwrite.o
fwrite.c:11:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
   11 | #include <zlib.h>      // for compression to .gz
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:252: fwrite.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'data.table'
* removing 'C:/Users/imelf/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/data.table'

The downloaded source packages are in
        'C:\Users\imelf\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmWL9ps\downloaded_packages'
Warning message:
In install.packages("data.table") :
  installation of package 'data.table' had non-zero exit status
>

Can anyone help here?

The build logs you have posted show you installing 32-bit package mingw-w64-i686-zlib
That cannot possibly be used by your 64-bit R compiler. zlib.h is not found because
the 32-bit package installs it in a path where 64-bit build will not and should not look.
The 64-bit package mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib is the right one but we do not know
what went wrong with that because you haven't posted that build log.
Update your post to show it instead.

Note what R said about data.table: WARNING: this package has a configure script. It probably needs manual configuration
That will remain true with 64-bit zlib and likely predicts the cause of any build failure.

Can you try again? Now a binary build for version 1.15.4 is also available for R 4.2 on Windows.

Hello Ralf, now I can again install.packages("data.table") and then the installation worked just fine. I could execute a small test program. Thanks a lot. All the best, Florian

A new version of the library ( version 1.15.4 is also available for R 4.2 on Windows ) became available and then the command install.packages("data.table") just worked fine.
I could then compile and run the following example program
library("data.table");

DT = data.table(x = rep(c("a","b","c"), each = 3), y = c(1, 3, 6), v = 1:9);

print(DT);

